# Проблема со вставкой некоторых символов в MySQL

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, php, mysql

Пытаюсь вставить в БД текст с некоторыми специфическими символами, типа: ← → ∞ ×.
Запись в БД появляется, но все эти символы заменены на знаки вопроса.
Сама БД на `utf-general-ci`, скрипты тоже в `utf-8`.
Если пытаюсь добавить запись с этими символами через `phpMyAdmin` — получаю предупреждение:

> **Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: 'xE2x86x90xE2x86x92' for column 'content' at row 1**

Как вставить этим символы?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте кодировку в MySQL - `utf8mb4`. Символы будут сохраняться, как 4-ёх байтные.
`utf8_general_ci` сохраняет символы, как 3-ёх байтные и происходит ошибка, когда вы вставляете 4-ёх байтный символ.

Правильная настройка - https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет это:

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Воспользовался похожей ф-цией htmlentities(), т.к. htmlspecialchars() преобразовывает не все символы. А как быть тогда с символами < и >, которые используются для html-тегов, обратно их преобразовывать с помощью str_replace("&lt;", "<", $str)? Или есть другой способ?

Comment: Это "костыль" — вроде бы помогает выкрутиться, но порождает новые проблемы, которые требуют своих костылей. Правильный ответ дал wapplay: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443229/176610.

Answer (score 0):

Такое чувство что это проблема phpMyAdmin. Или раньше существовали см. [brugbart.com/Articles/phpmyadmin-utf8-problem](http://brugbart.com/Articles/phpmyadmin-utf8-problem)